# Writing an array as a comma separated list to screen

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arrays, string

Now it seems like a really simple question and I may just be being thick, but what I'm trying to achieve is basically print an array to screen in the following format:

Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4

Although I say to screen, as that was the best way I could describe it, I'm actually writing it to the page inside some Javascript.

The way I'm currently going about writing it out is as follows:

```
for each b in theDates
    Response.Write("'" + b.CallDate + "',")
next
```

But obviously that returns a string of `Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4,`.

Is there a simple way of getting rid of the last comma or am I going about this completely wrong?

Comment: Just using String.Substring(0, yourString.length -1) not ok?

Comment: Didn't think of that to be fair.

Comment: I'm surprised you chose an aswer that does the same thing you wanted to avoid. The code to do that was written by Douglas. Read his answer and my subsequent vb edit.

Comment: @In Sane What happens if the string is zero length ?

Comment: @MarkJ - Valid point. Though a string length check can additionally always be added - i was just trying to actually confirm if my understanding of the question was correct with that earlier comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method. Not sure about VB but something like that:

```
Response.Write(String.Join(", ", theDates.Select(Function(n) "'" & n.CallDate & "'").ToArray()))
```

Answer (score 6):

Try `String.Join` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)). My VB is rusty, but hopefully you can read this C#:

```
var datesInQuotes = theDates.Select(date => "'" + date.CallDate + "'");

Response.Write(String.Join(", ", datesInQuotes));
```

Comment: I'm surprised the OP chose an answer that does not address his question. It leaves the trailing comma AND a space AND an inverted comma! This is the code that does what he/she requested.

Comment: The VB.NET equivalent is `Response.Write(String.Join(", ", theDates.Select(Function(d) "'" & d.CallDate & "'")))` Note that the OP wanted the CallDate of each date.

Comment: @Alex: Cheers, fixed that up. The chosen answer only sets the st variable in the loop, the Response.Write always ends with "'". A good reason not to use that code, it's easy to miss-read what it does!

Comment: @Alex: I don't end up with the issue you mentioned at all with the accepted answer. I have infact tried all of the answers received in this question and received the same result as that.

I will be considering the string.join method as the final method in the application based on one of Douglas' comments, but right now, it does what I want.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, String.Join is what you want in this case.

More generically: you've got to either detect when you're at the the *last* element and *not append* a comma, or detect when you're at the *first* element and *not prepend* a comma.

Typically it's easier to detect when you're at the first, so:

```
dim firstDone as bool = false
for each b in theDates
    if firstDone then Response.Write (",")
    Response.Write("'" + b.CallDate + "'")
    firstDone = true
next
```

(*Excuse my rusty vb)*

Comment: Your code leaves a trailing comma. I'm sure the OP specifically said he wanted to get `'rid of the last comma'`

Comment: @Alex I don't think it does leave a trailing comma. Every time it writes a comma, it writes a date afterwards.

Comment: @Alex, I've renamed my variable, does that make it easier to understand?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to String.join this.

```
st="'"
for each b in theDates
    Response.Write(st + b.CallDate + "'")
    st=", '"
next
```

Comment: Obviously this works, but I think that using String.Join to join strings expresses the intent more clearly, so it should still be considered.

Comment: Agreed. I'm considering changing the code to string.join anyway for the final version, though currently this does the job. In fact all the answers I've been given do pretty much.

Comment: You C# people are strange folks.

Comment: String.Join is obvious enough. The lambda functions do look a bit odd until you get used to them.

Answer (score 0):

No, you aren't wrong - totally.

Loop through theDates and put the data into a string.

After you are done looping, remove the last comma:

myString.Remove(myString.Length - 1, 1);

Response.Write(myString)

A side note:  You really shouldn't output to the screen with Response.Write.  You should set the text of a server control as your output.  A label is perfectly fine.  You will notice that your text won't appear where you think it will if you don't.

Comment: This'll build the string twice in memory, it'd be better to build it correctly from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the comma in front of each item except the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to do just as you were doing, and then use the Response.Remove(s.Length-1, 1)

Answer (score 0):

In C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < theDates.Length; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        Response.Write(",");
    }
    Response.Write(theDates[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all too complicated. Keep it simple

```
dim st as string ="'"
for each b in theDates
   Response.Write(st + b.CallDate + "'")
   st=", '"
next
response.write (st.TrimEnd(New Char() {" ", ","})
```